# FFT on RaspPi's GPU?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpu, fft

I am currently working on a Raspberry Pi project in which I am trying to calculate a FFT on some numpy arrays containing some measurement data. I would like to get this done on the GPU to free resources on the CPU. I found the GPU_FFT library of Andrew Holme that apparently allows exactly that.

http://www.aholme.co.uk/GPU_FFT/Main.htm

However, I do not know how to use this library exactly (I read the included instructions) as I have no knowledge of interaction between Python and C (I have never used C before). Further, I could not find any instructions on how to use GPU_FFT on the internet.

Is there any documentation/explanation that I could not find myself or can I use other Python libaries like PyFFT?

Comment: There are a few different ways to interface Python with C code, I would recommend looking into Cython - http://cython.org/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I knew of Cython but I hoped to avoid it. Looks like I have to look into it anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Mathematica package on the rpi? I haven't but they advertise that their code is very fast and use the gpu.